# How can I improve to get unblocked?

Tags: support, post-ban

Can someone please help me improve my questions and get me unblocked, because I have no idea where I can improve. I have read the Ts and Cs countless times and I've been blocked for months now.

Specifically targeting one of my questions which I did edit as I was told. But nothing seems to have made a difference, I was simply made fun off and my question disregarded...

Comment: Did you read the post that explains the question ban and how it works?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, he .. doesn't have a lot to work with as far as improving his existing questions goes. A case of getting off on the wrong foot.

Comment: @TimPost I have the same problem. Can't figure out how can I improve my questions to get unblocked. It doesn't seem to be bad question, but very specific and only interested to those people who faced the same problem. Does that mean that i don't have any chance to get unblicked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are times that even after you've figured out what makes a good question, the questions that you have just .. can't be improved. They're like lead weights that you can't shake off. You've been answering where you can, editing where you can and doing what you can to show that you actually care about the place so ...

[Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and link to this meta post when you do, we'll see what we can do to help. The blocks are designed to cause folks that *will never get it* to simply go away, I'm working on improving them, so that folks simply getting off on the wrong foot actually stand a chance of getting themselves out of it. Stack Overflow [can make people better writers and communicators over time](http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/), I don't like seeing folks that actually stand a chance not get one.

We all once sucked a little more than we do today, after all.

Comment: yeah this has shown me a different side to SO than what I have witnessed before I am really interested in writing code and making my own programs and stuff but like ive said on some of my questions I honestly don't know where to start I have started codecademy which is an online training program for coders so hopefully I can contribute more effectively in the future. this has shown me that people do actually care about newbies to coding even with the really high standards that is maintained on this site :)

Comment: I have contacted the site as you advised sorry it took so long for me to react I have been busy with work and the like

Comment: Out of nearly 100 questions, i have 4 posts that are negative....2 are just -1.... and i cant ask anything or do anything with my account.